# Can I reference "this" when calculating Distance in the Driver dialog?

Tags: drivers

Is it possible to reference this/self in the "Object 1" or "Object 2" Distance inputs?

[image]

Comment: This is [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You should give details of what you are trying to do so we can help find a good solution to exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie This particular driver is applied to a camera named "Camera.01". I would love to have something like "{this}" in the Object input, instead of "Camera.01". (I.e. the driver works when I enter "Camera.01" in the Object 1 input.)